# How to check if Large Text is enabled in Accessibility options Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I check weather Large Text option is enabled for the Android device?

I saw an example with

```
Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
float scale = c.fontScale;
```

but I couldn't make it work for Xamarin. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration(Resources.Configuration);

 if (config.FontScale == 1.3F)
 {
    //do something
 }
```

I used this code in my fragment and it worked for me.

Comment: I wouldn't compare floats with `==` since `FontScale` might be some odd value like `1.29999995231628`. But nevertheless, `new Configuration(Resources.Configuration).FontScale` helped me to detect this accessibility setting.